# How to pass Authorization Header Token in api call in angular

Tags: angular, api, http

I am using a get api call to fetch the data from json doc using http. But i have enabled authorization to only token bearer. I want to pass the value of token (which i can get through `localStorage.getItem("token");`) in my Authorization in the headers when i call the get request.

**API.SERVICE.TS**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClient, HttpRequest, HttpEventType, HttpHeaders, HttpParams, HttpEvent, HttpErrorResponse, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getTransferIp(){
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3003/transferip').map(res => res.json() );
  }

}
```

Currently i am allowed to fetch the data only when i turn off the auth in my node server get router...
But i dont want to do that and also without using interceptor

Attatching Node Server Files below...

**AUTH.JS**

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const User = require('../models/user')

const auth = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const token = req.header('Authorization').replace('Bearer ', '')
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, 'mango@123')
        const user = await User.findOne({ _id: decoded._id, 'tokens.token': token })

        if (!user) {
            throw new Error()
        }

        req.token = token
        req.user = user
        next()
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(401).send({ error: 'Please authenticate.' })
    }
}

module.exports = auth
```

**TRANSFERIP.JS (ROUTER)**

```
const express = require('express')
const TransferIp = require('../models/transferip')
const auth = require('../middleware/auth')
const router = new express.Router()

router.post('/transferip', auth, async (req, res) => {
    const task = new TransferIp({
        ...req.body,
        owner: req.user._id
    })

    try {
        await task.save()
        res.status(201).send(task)
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(400).send(e)
    }
})
router.get('/transferip', auth, function(req, res, next) {
    TransferIp.find(function (err, events) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      res.json(events);
    });
});

module.exports = router
```

**SCREENSHOT OF SUCCESSFUL GET REQUEST WITH TOKEN USING POSTMAN**
[image]

Comment: You can use an interceptor. https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try like this:

Use **HttpClient**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient,HttpHeaders  } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getTransferIp() {
    let header = new HttpHeaders().set(
      "Authorization",
       localStorage.getItem("token")
    );

    return this.http.get("http://localhost:3003/transferip", {headers:header});
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using map, which version of Angular are u using

Comment: im using 8.2
btw getting this error while trying ur answer
```
Argument of type 'HttpHeaders' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestOptionsArgs'.
  Property 'headers' is private in type 'HttpHeaders' but not in type 'RequestOptionsArgs'
```

Comment: Use httpclient, constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

Comment: Can you try the latest?

Comment: tried. no luck :( btw im not getting the 2nd comment error. but i am not able to fetch the data as i am getting 401:unauthorized

Comment: What kind of authorization does your backend have? Btoa? Bearer? Try it using postman and show how it worked

Comment: i have added more details in the question. please check

Comment: In authorization header, before the value, you didn't append 'Bearer' or anything else?

Comment: Check the modified answer. Remove `"Bearer " +`

Comment: tried but still noo....
```GET http://localhost:3003/transferip 401 (Unauthorized)```

Comment: Well, No idea then, this the way this is done. You can check `localStorage.getItem("token")` if this correct

Answer (score 2):

To intercept http requests in angular, you can write a service that implements `HttpsInterceptor` interface from `common/http` module.

```
 @Injectable()
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor() { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const token = 'token...'; // your auth token
    if (authorized) { // your authorized  logic
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `${token}`
        }
      });
    }

    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

Don't forget providing your service in your module.ts file

```
{provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: TokenInterceptor},
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create an interceptor to add the `Authorization` header for every request.

> https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8

If you want to add the header for only this specific request, temporarily, you can use something like this.

```
getTransferIp(){ {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    const header = new Headers({ 'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}` });
    const options = {
       headers: header,
    };

    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3003/transferip', options);   
}
```

Comment: in the network tab of your browser, does the request contain the Authorization header?

Comment: yes it does. and fyi when i get the request through postman adding the token, it works

Comment: Is it a cors issue? Is there an options request before the api request that fails?  In the console of the browser, is there a Cross Origin error?

Comment: @JasonWhite yes, I have similar issue, and I get CORS error, even tho I have CORS handling on backend, can you help here? Also I have slightly different issue since I am using angular 9.

Comment: @Petar If you're getting a CORS issue, there is most likely something wrong with the way your backend is configured.  CORS request are sent/handled by the browser and not Angular so the issue is most likely not Angular related.  Without seeing any source code, it's hard to tell the issue.